# Python bash output into string

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, boot

I have RaspberryPi and I've made a Python script that sends me an email when it boots up. The only problem that I have is the Pi changes IPs quite often (DHCP), so I want for it to also include output of commands:

```
hostname -I

curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

in the email.

Comment: could show us some code or what you have tried so we can help?

Comment: Please show your Python script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `subprocess` function returns the results of the commands in a string that you can attach to your email message:

```
import subprocess
host = subprocess.check_output(['hostname', '-I'], shell=True, universal_newlines=True) # a string is returned
curl = subprocess.check_output(['curl', 'ipinfo.io/ip'], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

You can call `rstrip()` on both strings to get rid of any trailing newline character.

Comment: check_output appears to be python 2.7+.  for python 2.6 and lower, look up subprocess.Popen and attempt the same thing.

Comment: hostname -I thing worked with a bit modified code (instead of ['hostname', '-I'] I did ['hostname -I'])
When I modified curl same way it shows me progress or something of downloaded file...